# Read in R an excel file with header of two rows using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to read in a header with two rows into R like below

```
Gram   Nanogram
(g)     (ng)
1        2 
1        4
```

to

```
Gram (g)   Nanogram (ng)
 1         2
 1         4
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would be best if you posted your data with `dput`.

Comment: Which function are you using to read the excel file? The simplest way would probably be to skip the first two lines and add the column names after reading the data. Column names should not have spaces or parentheses. While you can include them, the consequence is always having to quote the name, e.g. "Gram (g)" which can get tiresome and lead to errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(
  Gram = c("(g)", 1, 1),
  Nanogram = c("(ng)", 2, 4)
)


colnames(df) <- paste(colnames(df), df[1,], sep = " ")

library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% slice(-1)

> df1
  Gram (g) Nanogram (ng)
1        1             2
2        1             4
```